# CMakeFetchContent fails

Tags: git, cmake

our project consists of multiple (shared) git repositories.
Currently we are cloning theese git repositories using a shell script executed before CMake build.

I'd like to get rid of the shell script and perform all steps from within cmake.

Now I found ExternalProject and FetchContent

I started up with ExternalProject_Add

```
function(CloneRepository repositoryURL branchName projectName sourceDir)
ExternalProject_Add(
    "${projectName}"
    GIT_REPOSITORY "${repositoryURL}"
    SOURCE_DIR "${sourceDir}"
    GIT_TAG "origin/${branchName}"
    CONFIGURE_COMMAND ""
    BUILD_COMMAND ""
    INSTALL_COMMAND ""
endfunction(CloneRepository)
```

This worked nicely, however - as stated in the reference - cloning is performed at build time not a configure time. I'd like cloning to happen at configure time (just clone, no build)

That's when I found FetchContent

```
function(TestoCloneRepository repositoryURL branchName projectName sourceDir)
  message("Starting to clone ${projectName} into ${sourceDir}")
  FetchContent_Declare(
    "${projectName}"
    GIT_REPOSITORY "${repositoryURL}"
    SOURCE_DIR "${sourceDir}"
    GIT_TAG "origin/${branchName}"
    CONFIGURE_COMMAND ""
    BUILD_COMMAND ""
    INSTALL_COMMAND ""
  )
  FetchContent_MakeAvailable(${projectName})

endfunction(TestoCloneRepository)
```

Now the content of this function is the same however the ExternalProject_Add adds the repository but FetchContent fails at configuring with no reason given in the console output

So here are my questions:

1. Can I somehow get more error Outout? CMakeError.log is empty as well
2. Can I get some progress report? GIT_PROGRESS does not seem to be
   available for fetch content
3. Do you have any ideas why this is not
   working

Comment: "FetchContent fails at configuring with no reason given in the console output" - For any configuration error It should be at least the **error message**. Please, show it (add to the question post).

Comment: Pls see my Answer. Unfortunately VS 2022 does not print any error. Just "CMake Generation was aborted". I Could post the output but this is in German. So I'm not sure if this is actually helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I did some testing. It looks like this is a VS 2022 related issue.

When configuring my project from VS Code or CMake GUI (3.21) there is no error.
The Git Repository I'm checking out is quite huge. I guess that VS 2022 is running in some sort of timeout.
I'll post a bug report a Microsoft.